# Deploying secrets.yml with Chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra

How does one go about deploying a Rails secrets.yml file to your server when building it with Chef?

I'm currently using Chef/Berkshelf/knife-solo.

My secrets.yml file is obviously not being committed to my publicly accessible github repo. I could commit it with references to environment variables, but those variables would have to be setup somewhere in my publicly accessible Chef github repo as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `chef-solo` (better: chef-zero) setups I recommend using encrypted data bags. They became a lot easier to use with chef12:

https://docs.chef.io/chef/essentials_data_bags.html

Just keep the encryption secret out of git (using .gitignore) and use the default file name `encrypted_data_bag_secret`.

Use `knife -z` (local mode) to create/update data bags:

```
# create secret
openssl rand -base64 512 | tr -d '\r\n' > encrypted_data_bag_secret

# add encrypted_data_bag_secret to .gitignore

# convert your .yml file to .json
ruby -rYAML -rjson -e "puts YAML.load_file('secrets.yml').to_json"

# create encrypted data bag, don't remove/overwrite the id key!
EDITOR=vim knife data bag create -z apps railsapp --encrypt --secret-file encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

Convenience settings in your .chef/knife.rb:

```
 local_mode true    # makes -z default
 knife[:secret_file] = 'encrypted_data_bag_secret' # default for --secret-file
```

Recipe: Just map the data bag item ".to_yaml", e.g. map the structure 1:1 so you don't have to write a complex recipe logic, except of loading the data bag item + using the template-resource.

Comment: Chef vault is another option for keeping secrets encrypted. It has the advantage of solving the problem of how to manage the key that decrypts the data but can be tricky to use as it relies on the node existing first. No perfect solution, but 2 main options. See: https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault

Comment: Chef-Vault doesn't work with Chef-Solo because it uses the Chef-server client key to encrypt credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. I've gotten side-tracked, but will be circling back in a bit....

Answer (score 0):

Went ahead and accepted Roland's answer because it favors built in functionality of chef and would ultimately work. I started down that path and it just felt like 'a lot', as well as bleeding logic from my app into the chef repo and the conversion between json and yaml was annoying.

In the end, I just added the symmetric-encryption gem to my project, and am encrypting the `secrets.yml` file before exposing it on github. I also created two rake tasks...`rake secrets:encrypt` to run locally whenever I need to change secrets and `rake secrets:decrypt` which I run immediately after chef clones the project repo to build the `secrets.yml` file.

I added the encryption key to `.gitignore` and deploy it using vagrant's file provisioner.

Would not necessarily recommend this way, but it's here if anyone prefers it...

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'symmetric-encryption'

namespace :secrets do

  task "encrypt" do
    SymmetricEncryption.load!(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/symmetric-encryption.yml'), 'production')
    SymmetricEncryption::Writer.open(encrypted_secrets_file, encryption_options) do |file| 
      file.write(File.read(decrypted_secrets_file))
    end
  end

  task "decrypt" do
    SymmetricEncryption.load!(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/symmetric-encryption.yml'), 'production')
    File.open(decrypted_secrets_file, 'w') do |file|       file.write(SymmetricEncryption::Reader.open(encrypted_secrets_file).read)    end      
  end
end

def encryption_options
  { header: false, random_key: false, random_iv: false }
end

def encrypted_secrets_file
  File.join(Rails.root, 'config/encrypted_secrets')
end

def decrypted_secrets_file
  File.join(Rails.root, 'config/secrets.yml')
end
```